Take min and max dates for a sequence along a column
I have the following dataframe:
timeseries = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", periods=10, freq="m")
df = pd.DataFrame(data = ["a","a","b","a","a","c","c","c","a","a"], index = timeseries, columns = ['var'])
print(df)
           var
2018-01-31  a
2018-02-28  a
2018-03-31  b
2018-04-30  a
2018-05-31  a
2018-06-30  c
2018-07-31  c
2018-08-31  c
2018-09-30  a
2018-10-31  a


I want to extract the minimum and maximum dates for each uninterrupted sequence of values in column "var" and assign them as additional columns. Desired result is:
           var   min Date   max Date
1/31/2018   a   1/31/2018   2/28/2018
2/28/2018   a   1/31/2018   2/28/2018
3/31/2018   b   3/31/2018   3/31/2018
4/30/2018   a   4/30/2018   5/31/2018
5/31/2018   a   4/30/2018   5/31/2018
6/30/2018   c   6/30/2018   8/31/2018
7/31/2018   c   6/30/2018   8/31/2018
8/31/2018   c   6/30/2018   8/31/2018
9/30/2018   a   9/30/2018   10/31/2018
10/31/2018  a   9/30/2018   10/31/2018

for example in column "var" the first time value "a" appears is on 1/31/2018 and then it goes again "a" on 2/28/2018 before it is interrupted by "b". So for min and max dates we will have 1/31/2018 and 2/28/2018.
I thought I can achieve that with groupby operation but didn't manage since groupby aggregates all "a" or "b" or "c" etc.

You need to convert your index to_series, then form a custom grouper (with shift+cumsum) and use a groupby.transform:
# group successive values
group = df['var'].ne(df['var'].shift()).cumsum()
# form grouper and get transform
t = df.index.to_series().groupby(group).transform
# compute min/max
df['min Date'] = t('min')
df['max Date'] = t('max')

Output:
           var   min Date   max Date
2018-01-31   a 2018-01-31 2018-02-28
2018-02-28   a 2018-01-31 2018-02-28
2018-03-31   b 2018-03-31 2018-03-31
2018-04-30   a 2018-04-30 2018-05-31
2018-05-31   a 2018-04-30 2018-05-31
2018-06-30   c 2018-06-30 2018-08-31
2018-07-31   c 2018-06-30 2018-08-31
2018-08-31   c 2018-06-30 2018-08-31
2018-09-30   a 2018-09-30 2018-10-31
2018-10-31   a 2018-09-30 2018-10-31


import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


timeseries = pd.date_range("1990-01-01", periods=10, freq="ME")

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data=["a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a"], index=timeseries, columns=['id'])
print(df)
"""
            id
1990-01-31   a
1990-02-28   a
1990-03-31   b
1990-04-30   a
1990-05-31   a
1990-06-30   c
1990-07-31   c
1990-08-31   c
1990-09-30   a
1990-10-31   a
"""
# Find groups of successive values
group = df['id'].ne(df['id'].shift()).cumsum()

df['group'] = group
# Calculate min and max dates for each group
min_dates = df.groupby(group).apply(lambda x: x.index.min())
max_dates = df.groupby(group).apply(lambda x: x.index.max())

# Merge min and max dates with the original DataFrame
df['min_Date'] = group.map(min_dates)
df['max_Date'] = group.map(max_dates)

print(df)
"""
          id  group   min_Date   max_Date
1990-01-31  a      1 1990-01-31 1990-02-28
1990-02-28  a      1 1990-01-31 1990-02-28
1990-03-31  b      2 1990-03-31 1990-03-31
1990-04-30  a      3 1990-04-30 1990-05-31
1990-05-31  a      3 1990-04-30 1990-05-31
1990-06-30  c      4 1990-06-30 1990-08-31
1990-07-31  c      4 1990-06-30 1990-08-31
1990-08-31  c      4 1990-06-30 1990-08-31
1990-09-30  a      5 1990-09-30 1990-10-31
1990-10-31  a      5 1990-09-30 1990-10-31

"""

